# My mysqli table isn't shown properly. I need assistance with my code because I can't find my error

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make this look pretty with the use of bootstrap. And inserting works properly, the table works properly on the old page. But the new one shows this. It's the same code... practically  [image] I've tried to check if all quoutations are in place and I find it hard to tell. But I think mysqli_close and a few other signs aren't properly places but I just can't figure out whats wrong and where. What am I missing here?

EDIT: replaced misplaced "" and also all my files are in the same folder

EDIT": I've discovered that if I use .php instead of .html it works as it should. What does this mean? And how do I get it in my larger site?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="nam" placeholder="Title" id="nam"><br>
  <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Author" id="author"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>

<div>
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Added</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>

            <?php
                    include_once "dbConfig.php";
                    $db=mysqli_connect($server, $usr,$pwd,$db);
                            if($db == false){die("no con");}
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM $dbTable";
                            mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error');

                            $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                    echo "\t<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['author'] .
                                            "</td><td>" . $row[bookread] .
                                            "</td><td><input type='checkbox'" 
                                            value='".$row['name']."'  name='".$row['name']."'</td></tr><br>";
                                    }
                            mysqli_close($db);
                    ?>
            </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: why is there `</head>` at the bottom? why no opening/closing html tags?

Comment: Looks like unparsed code. Thus you ought to mention in what file your PHP resides in / how it's included / from where / what templating approach was used. -- Als question titles should be **summaries**, not spammed with pleas for assistence.

Comment: I'm very new at this. I've moved it now, thanks

Comment: it still is not valid html - you are missing the `<html>` and `</html>` tags and have unclosed elements

Comment: `"I've discovered that if I use .php instead of .html it works as it should"` thats not surprising - the server is setup to run .php files through the php interpreter, but just return the content of .html files

Comment: seriously? correct the other issues mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP wasn't supported. Solved by editing php.ini

Answer (score -1):

You had several basic HTML errors in there - no `html` tags, no `title`, unclosed input elements with bad quotation and some others. I'd urge you to indent your code properly - it always makes it easier to find errors and to follow the structure/logic.

The sql you have is ( potentially ) vulnerable to sql injection and you should check that there is a recordset available before trying to iterate through it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="insert.php" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="nam" placeholder="Title" id="nam"><br>
          <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Author" id="author"><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Add">
        </form>

        <div>
            <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Author</th>
                        <th>Added</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                    </tr>


                    <?php

                        include_once "dbConfig.php";
                        $db=mysqli_connect($server, $usr,$pwd,$db);

                        if($db == false){die("no con");}

                        $query = "SELECT * FROM $dbTable";  /* this makes it potentially vulnerable */
                        mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error');

                        $result = mysqli_query( $db, $query );

                        if( $result && mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ){

                            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
                                echo "
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                                        <td>{$row['author']}</td>
                                        <td>{$row['bookread']}</td>
                                        <td><input type='checkbox' value='{$row['name']}' name='{$row['name']}' /></td>
                                    </tr>";
                            }
                        }
                        mysqli_close($db);
                    ?>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                echo "\t<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['author'] .
                                        "</td><td>" . $row['bookread'] .
                                        "</td><td><input type='checkbox'
                                        value='".$row['name']."'  name='".$row['name']."'</td></tr><br>";
                                }
                        mysqli_close($db);
```

Comment: the above suffers from one of the original issues - the `input` element remains unclosed